# How can I validate a form collection must have X number of elements?

Tags: validation, symfony

I have a form with a field that is a collection, and this collection must have a fixed number of elements. How I can validate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a custom callback validator for the entity owning the collection.

If you have a Cart entity and a collection of Products for example, you should do:

```
...............
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
...............
 * @Assert\Callback(
 *  methods={"hasCorrectNumberOfProducts"}
 * )
class Cart
{
...........

public function hasCorrectNumberOfProducts(ExecutionContext $context)
{
    $propertyPath = $context->getPropertyPath();
    $correct = 666;

    if(!count($this->getProducts()) == $correct) {
        $context->setPropertyPath($propertyPath . '.products');
        $context->addViolation('Incorrect number of products!', array(), null);
    }
}
......
```